# Firebase not sending same number of events to Google Analytics through GTM

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

It's been a week since I setup Firebase for my iOS app. I am using Google Tag Manager (GTM) to pass the events to Google Analytics (GA). The events and variables on the GTM seem to be setup correctly and I can see all the events sent to GA.

The problem is - The **number of events** sent to GA is not equal to what Firebase is recording. Firebase data is of course correct as I can match the numbers from the backend. GA doesn't seem to receive the same number of events. I cannot see any error during debug. Please get back if you have seen this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the answer found in Tag Manager Forum -

> This is an iOS issue I think. What you should do, is calling [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch]... when UIApplicationWillResignActive happens. We do this in all iOS apps with Firebase and GTMv5, since Firebase only dispatch queued Firebase-events when going to background.

[Here is the solution](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/GRpixUPJE6M;context-place=forum/tag-manager) to this issue, just in case anyone else faces it in future and wants to look at the full thread, thanks to Jørn.